# How to make website scable to any browser size and mobile

Tags: html, css

I've made a basic about page, and I don't know how to make it scalable to mobile or other display sizes. I haven't really tried anything because I'm not knowledgeable enough in HTML. Here is the code, any help would be amazing!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/main.css">
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1″>

<html>
<style> 
html { 
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(http://www.superchargedfood.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/HEALTHY-LATIN-2.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.header-right 
{
    font-family: Snell Roundhand;
font-size: 30px;
color: white;
text-align: right;
margin-top: -75px;
margin-right: 30px;
}

#green{
    background-color: #C19A6B;
    height: 375px;
    background: rgba(193, 154, 107, 0.7);
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-right: 12%;
    margin-top: 3.75%;
    border-radius: 37.5px;

}
#green1{
    background-color: #EDC9AF;
    height: 375px;
    background: rgba(237, 201, 175, 0.7);
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-right: 12%;
    margin-top: 2.25%;
    border-radius: 37.5px;

}
#green2{
    background-color: #C19A6B;
    height: 375px;
    background: rgba(193, 154, 107, 0.7);
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-right: 12%;
    margin-top: 2.25%;
    border-radius: 37.5px;

}

#greenText{
    color:white;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
margin-left: 28%;
margin-top: 10%;
margin-right: 20%; 
max-width: 525px;
text-align: center;
}

img{
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
   
}
</style>
  <h1 > <span style="font-family:Snell Roundhand;   margin-left: 525px; color: white; font-size: 67.5px;"> Joey's Resturant </span>   <h1>

<div class="header-right">
        <a style="color: white;" href="Drink Chooser copy.php">Order</a>
        <a style="color: white;"href="email.php">Contact</a>
        <a style="color: white;"href="Home page.html">About</a>
        <a style="color: white;"href="menue.php">Menue</a>
      </div>


<div id="green">
        <div id="greenText">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel suscipit dui. Cras a risus a massa semper dictum. Nunc ex mi, varius nec mauris eget, tempus tempus libero. Suspendisse.                    </div>
                    <img id="pics" style=" opacity:1;  margin-top: 3%; margin-left: 3%;" src="pics/shop1-copy.png" >   

    </div>
   

    <div id="green1">
            <div id="greenText">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel suscipit dui. Cras a risus a massa semper dictum. Nunc ex mi, varius nec mauris eget, tempus tempus libero. Suspendisse.
                      </div>
                      <img id="pics" style=" opacity:1;  margin-top: 3%; margin-left: 3%;" src="pics/shop2.png" >   

        </div>
       

        <div id="green2">
                <div id="greenText">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel suscipit dui. Cras a risus a massa semper dictum. Nunc ex mi, varius nec mauris eget, tempus tempus libero. Suspendisse.                                </div>
                                <img id="pics" style=" opacity:1;  margin-top: 3%; margin-left: 3%;" src="pics/dogs.png" >   

            </div>
           
</html>
```

I have no idea what to do. Do I need to change all the pizxel sizes? Should anything be based of pixels? How do I use em?

Answer (score 0):

Think you've made an error in the meta tag with the double comma's

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1″>
```

TRY

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It did help a little but still not good. Should all my measurements be in %? How do I make the font size scale as well?